# Is there a way to dynamically expose bindings in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

The question could be worded better, but basically, this is what I'm trying to do:

I am putting together an industry-specific editor for our application, basic functionality like Word but with some extra tools needed for health care.

The functionality is organized into logical groups, for example, clip commands (cut-copy-paste), alignment, etc; and these are represented in a ribbon control.

We need to create an instance of the editor with some mixture of these features based on context; e.g. sometimes we want to expose the "redaction" group, sometimes we want to expose the "imaging" group.

So rather than a large monolithic editor class with a bunch of toggles, I wanted to break off each of the individual commands into separate classes, and then group those into a view model for each logical group, something like this:

```
class Cut: ICommand {}
class Copy: ICommand {}

class ClipCommands {
    public ICommand Cut { get { return _cutCommand; } }
    public ICommand Copy { get { return _copyCommand; } }
}
```

So now I'm trying to figure out how I could dynamically expose those groups in the main editor viewmodel without hard-coding them.  I thought about something like the decorator pattern:

```
class ClipCommands: EditorBase
{
     ClipCommands(EditorBase editor) {}
     // expose my commands

     // (!?) how do I expose any others already attached?
}
```

Then I could just construct all of the functionality I want.

```
var editor = new EditorBase(new ClipCommands(new RedactCommands()));
```

But I'm lost on how to expose the data bindings that could have already been attached by any of the other groups.  Is this the wrong approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an Office-style Ribbon control then the correct UX pattern would be to put the groups into different tabs on the Ribbon and then control which tabs are visible at runtime

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>

...

<ribbon:RibbonTab Visibility="{Binding ShowThisRibbonTab, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
</ribbon:RibbonTab>
```

If you want to make groups within tabs visible then bind the visibility of the RibbonGroups instead

**EDIT** I think I misunderstood the question. Its not the UI you are having problems with, but the composition of your ViewModel.

You could set the DataContext of each RibbonGroup to a different ViewModel.

```
<ribbon:RibbonTab DataContext="{Binding EditViewModel}">
</ribbon:RibbonTab>
<ribbon:RibbonTab DataContext="{Binding FormatViewModel}">
</ribbon:RibbonTab>
<ribbon:RibbonTab DataContext="{Binding PrintViewModel}">
</ribbon:RibbonTab>
```

I implemented something similar where users could create their own buttons to go on the Ribbon control. I was using the Ribbon control from Actipro software. I changed the `RibbonGroup` item template to an `ItemsControl` with horizontal orientation and bound the `ItemsSource` to an "Actions" property in my ViewModel class, each generic Action class had a command for the button, which called an `Invoke` method that performed the action.

Comment: Yea, it wasn't the UI but the VM I'm struggling with.  The separate datacontext per tab would probably work if we had a one-to-one relationship between the tabs and the functionality they contain, but we don't.  One tab might need the functionality from 3 or 4 different groups of commands, which are also dynamically created based on context.

Comment: See edited answer. Create a generic class for each command, let your ViewModel decide which commands to load into a collection and edit the Ribbon template to allow you to bind the buttons to an ItemsSource.

Comment: Interesting approach, I didn't think about using a collection for the command bindings.  Thanks.